# Python cannot find certain windows executibles

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I can't seem to get some specifics executables to run in python on windows.
On running these executables I get a file not found error.

I can get other executables like winver.exe to run using multiple methods:

```
subprocess.Popen( [r"C:\Windows\System32\winver.exe"] )
subprocess.run( [r"C:\Windows\System32\winver.exe"] )
subprocess.run( ["winver"] )
subprocess.Popen( ["winver"] )
os.system( "winver" )
```

But I can't seem to get wsl, bash, ssh, or sftp working:

```
subprocess.Popen( [r"C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe"] )
subprocess.run( [r"C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe"] )
subprocess.run( ["wsl"] )
subprocess.Popen( ["wsl"] )
os.system( "wsl" )

subprocess.Popen( [r"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"] )
subprocess.run( [r"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe"] )
subprocess.run( ["bash"] )
subprocess.Popen( ["bash"] )
os.system( "bash" )

subprocess.Popen( [r"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"] )
subprocess.run( [r"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe"] )
subprocess.run( ["ssh"] )
subprocess.Popen( ["ssh"] )
os.system( "ssh" )

subprocess.Popen( [r"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sftp.exe"] )
subprocess.run( [r"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sftp.exe"] )
subprocess.run( ["sftp"] )
subprocess.Popen( ["sftp"] )
os.system( "sftp" )
```

Errors for sftp:

```
  File "d:/Griffin/Documents/Coding/Python/network.py", line 42, in <module>
    val = subprocess.Popen( [r"C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sftp.exe"] )
  File "C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Griffin/Documents/Coding/Python/network.py", line 44, in <module>
    val = subprocess.run( ["sftp"] )
  File "C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Griffin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

'sftp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Griffin/Documents/Coding/Python/network.py", line 48, in <module>
    os.chdir( "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH" )
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH'
```

In fact if I do a dir print out, those programs are not shown in the list.

```
os.chdir( "C:\Windows\System32" )
val = os.system( "dir" )

print( val )
```

If I try the same thing on the OpenSSH directory, it is not found entirely.

```
os.chdir( "C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH" )
val = os.system( "dir" )

print( val )
```

All of these work fine outside of python as you expect, and they work from .bat too.

Comment: can you post the stacktrace? note that the argument of chdir misses the raw prefix too. Please post .bat files that work too.

Comment: .bat file just contains a single line of just the name of the program (ssh/sftp/winver)